# Excel VBA worksheet.copy too big and fails

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a spreadsheet, that is quite large and has a lot of charts on it.

This spreadsheet is a "Master Sheet" and I need to use the data and charts in it to create lots of filtered down sheets for clients.

The master sheet isn't very big, only 7016 rows, but it has alot of charts (in the region of 100)

When I try to duplicate the mastersheet (prior to filtering it down) My code gets stuck and fails.

I've tried several things.

First I've already done copy and paste values on the master sheet (so there are no formulas)
and I looped through all the charts and replaced them with images instead of charts

then to duplicate the sheet I've tried

```
masterWorkbook.Sheets("Industry").Range("1:7016").Copy industrySheet.Range("A1")
```

and

```
masterWorkbook.Sheets("Industry").Copy after:=myWorkbook.Sheets(myWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

both methods take too long and excel eventually crashes out

I've also tried using first method and reducing the number of rows I copy at a time:

```
startRow = 1
endRow = 300

Do Until endRow > lastRow
    masterWorkbook.Sheets("Industry").Range(startRow & ":" & endRow).Copy industrySheet.Range("A" & startRow)
    startRow = endRow + 1
    endRow = startRow + 300
    If endRow > lastRow Then
        endRow = lastRow
    End If
Loop
```

At first I thought this would work, but again it gets stuck and excel eventually crashes out.

Are there any other approaches?

My main issue is the charts.

```
masterWorkbook.Sheets("Industry").Range("A1:M7016").Copy industrySheet.Range("A1")
```

works instantly, but it does copy the charts/images.

Comment: To copy only values, you could try `With masterWorkbook.Sheets("Industry").Range("A1:M7016"): industrySheet.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value: End With`, each colon (`:`) denoting a new row. Possibly you could reference the source range with `With masterWorkbook.Sheets("Industry").Range("A1").CurrentRegion` instead. Check if `Debug.Print .Address(0, 0)` returns the correct range (`A1:M7016`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) In case this post doesn't help you, let me know, I'll retract the close vote.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion, but I need the formatting as well

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem with creating data from one sheet to separated, filtered sheets. I tried copy-pasting values, yet it did not work for me well.

The soultion, that worked for me was to programatically generate Queries, that create new worksheets and add filetered data via PowerQuery.

```
Sub createQueries()
   
   'copy-paste column you want to use as a filter to a devSheet, remove duplicates
   
   activeworksheet.range("C:C").copy
   activeworkbook.Worksheets("devSheet").paste

    activeworkbook.Worksheets("devSheet").Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1
   
   'Find last value in devSheet
   
   Dim lastrow As Long
   Dim managers As Range
   
   lastrow = activeworkbook.Worksheets("devSheet").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
   
   'loop through all values in devSheet
   For Each managers In Sheets("devSheet").Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
       
       'Add query to the workbook, that will extract needed data
       
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:=managers, Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=""SOURCE TABLE NAME""]}[Content]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""COLUMN HEADERS""," & _
        " type text}, {""COLUMN HEADERS"", Int64.Type}"" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered Rows"" = Table.SelectRows(#""Changed Type"", each ([#""FILTERED COLUMN""] = """ & managers & """))" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered Rows"""
       'If you don't feel confident with an statement above, you can record creating a Query with needed filter and replace two lines above with adequate recorded code and the adjust filtered column as above
       
       
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = managers
        
     With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
          "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & managers & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
           , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
           .CommandType = xlCmdSql
           .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & managers & "]")
           .RowNumbers = False
           .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
           .PreserveFormatting = True
           .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
           .BackgroundQuery = True
           .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
           .SavePassword = False
           .SaveData = True
           .AdjustColumnWidth = True
           .RefreshPeriod = 0
           .PreserveColumnInfo = True
           .ListObject.DisplayName = managers
           .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

       End With
        
    Next managers

End Sub
```

Regarding the charts, I would recommend recreating them programatically in each worksheet via loop similar to the one creating queries. As I don't know the details of the charts, I can not help with specific code, however you can use below tutorial:
https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/charts-graphs/